# Using my models with NGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, scikit-learn, data-mining

I've come across this new tool of NGBoost from the Machine Learning group of Stanford, I was curious if peopel have started using it yet. They say that one can have a Base learner such as a regression tree etc, but looking at their examples I'm not sure on how my own model to this would be integrated.

Just mostly curious if anyone has used this tool yet.

PAPER: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.03225.pdf

Github: [GitHub](https://github.com/stanfordmlgroup/ngboost)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using NGBoost quite a lot.

From what I gather, NGBoost currently only supports SK-Learn-type base learners. So you can use something like XGBRegressor in the Base parameter of ngboost. I would mention that it significantly increases the training time in comparison to the default base learner though!